# Windows Batch: How to grab a Job ID from a log and set it to a variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables

I have a log file (job.log) that contains a jobID that is always changing.
How do I open this file and parse the job ID and store 761 to a variable so I can use it for other command references?  Again, this log will always have a different jobID so I'm looking for a dynamic way to do this.

```
"RUNNING","jobId":761,"logFileName":"outbox/logs/AQCONSOL-Finance_761.log
```

FYI, within my bat file, I will use the following command to download this log file...

```
call automate downloadfile "outbox/logs/AQCONSOL-Finance_"%jobid%".log"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\Q43128657.txt"
FOR /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=:," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET job=%%a
ECHO job is %job%

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `Q43128657.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Simply parse the line using `:` and `,` as delimiters and select the third token.

---

Revision to select file "rundatarule*.log"

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b /a-d /od "%sourcedir%\rundatarule*.log" ') DO SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\%%a"
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=3delims=:," %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO SET job=%%a
ECHO job is %job%

GOTO :EOF
```

The `dir` command lists matching files in `/b` basic form `/a-d` with no directorynames `/od` in order of date (just in case there are multiple files, select the very last chronologically) and processes that list, applying the entire name (in case there are separators) to `%%a` and thus assigning the reconstructed name (with the directory) to `filename1`.

It is considered good practice to format date-timestamps as ymdhms, not dmyhms as this provides an easily-sortable sequence.

Comment: Got it!  One last request.  What if the log file name is always changing? Log name: rundatarule_30_03_2017_05_17_46.log   How do I look for rundatarule*.log?

Comment: `/on` might not be the best idea, given the date/time format of `dd_mm_yyyy...`

Comment: @Stephan: Good catch. fixed and note added.